# If all of the values ​in the column are outside of a certain range, drop that column

Tags: python, pandas

data sample:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 132 |
| 15 | 42 |
| 14 | 51 |
| 18 | 41 |
| 29 | 100 |
| 21 | 132 |

Suppose I have a condition like: If all values ​​in a column **are not between 10 and 40**, drop that column.

According to this condition, I have to drop the **y column** in the data sample.
tried to use:

```
df.loc[:, (df >9 & df <40).any(axis=0)]
```

but I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do.  In two places, your requirement to drop is that all values in the column must be out of range.  Your code seems to be trying to filter that way, as well, but your data show that column `y` should be kept because of a single value (21) that is within range.

Comment: @Prune sorry. I entered a wrong value. edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overall logic is correct; the problem is operator precedence.  The bitwise operation has a higher precedence than "greater than", so your expression is not what you think.

You did apply DeMorgan's theorem correctly; you need only to fix your expression by forcing the operator precedence you want with parentheses:

```
df.loc[:, ((df > 9) & (df < 40)).any(axis=0)]
```

Comment: In addition to Ch3steR's answer, this solution also worked very well. thank you.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  What happened when you tried it with your original (erroneous) data?

Comment: My bad OP changed the sample data.

Comment: Yup -- the given data still isn't the best, since it doesn't differentiate between "all" and "any".  If we get a clear problem statement and your answer is correct (even if it takes an all/any change), I plan to delete mine as superfluous.

Comment: I examined my output and Ch3steR's answer is not exactly correct. `df.loc[:, (df.gt(9) & df.lt(40)).all()]` When I do it this way, it gives the right result. Apart from that, Prune's answer works without any editing.

Comment: I recommend that you post a clear set of requirements.  You need at least three columns: one with all values within range, one with all values out of range (you ready have those), and one column with mixed values.

Comment: @Ch3steR: thanks -- I was going to do it the other way: you edit yours, and I delete mine.  The main point is that OP has a solution.

Comment: @Prune No, I answered wrong I should be the one to delete. And yes all for the community which helped me way too much.